# c++ write vector elements to split files

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

Given I have a `vector<string> lines` which contain all the lines read from a file, how can i then write the contents of the vector back to a file except split it by x many lines per file. I'm more so stuck with the chunking problem rather than writing back to file. An example would be if

```
int offset = 10000;
std::vector<std::string> lines(27000);

...assuming lines has been initialized with lines
```

given the above I should have

file1 : 10000

file2 : 10000

file3: 7000

Comment: Use a loop to iterate through vector elements. Use the modulus operator to determine whether you've written the desired number of records per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, you just need a loop and an if statement.

```
ofstream output;
string filename = "filename";
int fileNum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    if(i % 10000 == 0){
        if(output.is_open()) output.close();
        output.open(filename + to_string(++fileNum));
    }
    output << vec.at(i);
}

output.close();
```

That will save files in "filename1", "filename2",  and "filename3" for a 27000 line file.

<sup>**Disclaimer:** Written free hand: may contain syntax errors.</sup>

Comment: Thanks :) , it really is more simple than I originally thought

Comment: Not a problem. If the only purpose of the program is to split the files, the vector is a middleman that can just be dropped.